# How to remove specific xmlns:ns from SOAP response

Tags: web-services, soap, namespaces, wsdl, jax-ws

Below is my sample SOAP response.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns4:createReservationResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.xyz2.com/documentation/createEnvironment/input" xmlns:ns3="http://webservices.xyz.com/documentation/reservations/createReservation/output" xmlns:ns4="http://webservices.xyz.com/documentation/reservations/createReservation/input" xmlns:ns5="http://webservices.xyz.com/documentation/reservations/cancelReservation/input" xmlns:ns6="http://webservices.xyz.com/documentation/reservations/cancelReservation/output">
 <return>
<!-- response data -->
</return>
 </ns4:createReservationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do i remove unwanted namespaces here in my case xmlns:ns2, xmlns:ns4, xmlns:ns5 and xmlns:ns6. I should only keep xmlns:ns3 in the response.

What should i change in my wsdl so that i can get the expected response as below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soap:Body>
          <ns4:createReservationResponse xmlns:ns3="http://webservices.xyz.com/documentation/reservations/createReservation/output">
     <return>
    <!-- response data -->
    </return>
     </ns4:createReservationResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Please help me out from this.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson The soap response which i posted is the sample one, but we have around 30 webservies in prod, and for each webservice response, the payload (response) size is very big, so we need to remove the unwanted xmlns ones from the response to reduce the payload size.

Comment: Can you add the wsdl you are using?